# Seurat : resolution=0 but 2 clusters

Tags: r, seurat

I did, QC, normalization and PCA of my data,
and used the code below.

```
gc1.1 <- FindNeighbors(gc1.1, dims = 1:40)
gc1.1 <- FindClusters(gc1.1, resolution = 0)
gc1.1 <- RunUMAP(gc1.1, dims = 1:40)
DimPlot(gc1.1, reduction = "umap", label = TRUE, repel = TRUE)
```

However, with resolution=0, I got 2 clusters
[image]

I need some help to know why and how did this happened

Answer (score 0):

Could you try increase `k.param` in the `FindNeighbors()` call, and re-run everything else?

i.e.

```
gc1.1 <- FindNeighbors(gc1.1, dims = 1:40, k.param = 30)
gc1.1 <- FindClusters(gc1.1, resolution = 0)
gc1.1 <- RunUMAP(gc1.1, dims = 1:40)
DimPlot(gc1.1, reduction = "umap", label = TRUE, repel = TRUE)
```